# Generating sequences from HMM

Tags: homework, hidden-markov-models, multiple-sequence-alignment

I encountered this question in a textbook (source: https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.721.2540&rep=rep1&type=pdf) and was trying to workout the solution for it. Was wondering for the last question, wouldn't the probability be 0?

[image: Question]

My working:

START -> M1 -> M2 -> M3 -> M4 -> M5 -> M6 -> M7 -> END

Probability Vector [A, T, C, G]

M1 : [0.6, 0.4, 0, 0]

M2 : [0.6, 0.4, 0, 0]

M3 : [0.4, 0.4, 0.2, 0]

M4 : [0.6, 0.4, 0, 0]

M5 : [0.4, 0.6, 0, 0]

M6 : [1, 0, 0, 0]

M7 : [0, 0, 0, 1]

To generate CTAAAAG = 0 * 0.4 * 0.4 * 0.6 * 0.4 * 1 * 1 = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Comments from other post migrated as answer]*

The parenthetical statement in the first bullet point says **without corrections**. In which case, if an unseen nucleotide has a probability of zero, the probability of the sequence is zero. If the unseen nucleotides had the probability of NaN, then the sequence has a probability of NaN, which is a more thorough solution.

The correction would be adding a small iota value to the probabilities to be non zero —**fudging** against the zero outcome you otherwise find, which may be the result of the training being too small. You have 5 training sequences, so the iota would be <1/5. Let's hypothetically assume that if you were to have picked a 6th MSA sequence it would have had the missing value, so you could set the iota at 1/6. The assumption that you may find that element were you to sample twice as many is more statistically sensible, so iota to 1/10.

I used the letter iota, which is common parlance for something small, but iota is a really bad in maths as it looks like a 1 with English handwriting or in print: you can call the fudge value anything.